# Tomcat is working in web browser but not in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a problems with starting Tomcat in eclipse. I think, I configured all environment variables in right way (JAVA_HOME, TOMCAT_HOME, PATH, JRE_HOME, ...). When I type localhost:8080 in webbrowser, I see Tomcats main page. In eclipse, I am trying to start server, but every time after 45 seconds i see:

> Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

Also there is an info (last line):

> INFO: Server startup in 697 ms

Had Anyone has the same situation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I needed to add to shortcut

> -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

And it works. But thank You all for Your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the amount of time?

`Open the Servers view -> double click tomcat -> drop down the Timeouts section`

Answer (score 0):

If you see the Tomcat home page when browsing to `localhost:8080`, then your Tomcat is already running. Eclipse should **not** try to start another Tomcat instance.

If you want to debug the code in an already running Tomcat, make sure that Tomcat has remote debugging enabled, and connect from Eclipse to "Remove Application".

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this [step-by-step tutorial](https://ayudaenjava.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/45/) to reinstall your server.

After that, don't forget refresh your server menu

Good luck! I hope this help you